# How can I capture only the beginning and end of a string, while avoiding the middle of a matched regex?

Tags: regex, bash, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to capture the very beginning and the very end of a matched regex with a grep command, but I don't want the middle of the string to be captured.

Here is the string:

```
href="file:///home/user/file" added="2023-09-07T21:58:58Z" modified="2023-09-07T22:27:45Z" visited="2023-09-07T21:58:58Z"
```

I want to capture `href="file:///home/user/file"`, exclude  `added="2023-09-07T21:58:58Z" modified="2023-09-07T22:27:45Z"` and capture `visited="2023-09-07T21:58:58Z"`

In order to do so, I have tried the following grep command:

```
$ grep -oP -m 10 'href="file:///.*(?="\sadded=".*visited=").*'
```

And here is the stdout:

```
href="file:///home/user/file" added="2023-09-07T21:58:58Z" modified="2023-09-07T22:27:45Z" visited="2023-09-07T21:58:58Z">
```

which is not the captured string I am looking for, since  `added="2023-09-07T21:58:58Z" modified="2023-09-07T22:27:45Z"` is present

I think the lookahead expression `(?="\sadded=".*visited=")` does not change the string match position, which is why the following `.*` captures the middle of the string, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Your sample does not contain `<` or `>` while your example output contains them. Which of these is wrong?

Comment: You can remove unwanted parts of a text with `sed`, so one possibility would be to use _sed_  instead of _grep_.

Answer (score 3):

A regex match is always a continuous substring of the string being matched against, so the `grep` command, designed to match a single pattern, isn't suitable for the task of avoiding specific patterns from a match.

You can use awk instead, set the field separator to `'='`, and set the input and output record separator to a space, so that you can easily filter records by the first field:

```
awk -F= -vRS=' ' -vORS=' ' '$1!~/added|modified/'
```

Demo: https://awk.js.org/?snippet=KdpB4M

Answer (score 2):

You *could* do something like

```
grep -o -e '^<bookmark href="[^"]*"' -e 'visited="[^"]*"$>' file
```

but for the more general case, `grep` seems like entirely the wrong tool for this.

```
sed -n 's/^\(<bookmark href="[^"]*"\).*\(visited="[^"]*"\)$>/\1\n\2/p' file
```

As always, if you are dealing with HTML / XML, the vastly superior approach is to use an actual XML parser instead.

Answer (score 1):

sed is a good tool for this task

```
sed 's/\(.*\) \(.*\) \(.*\) \(.*\)/\1 \4/' < file
```

where 'file' is a file containing the text.  Here I assume that each line contains exactly 4 groups separated by blanks. The first and fourth group are printed.